# How to figure out what is missing in Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm getting an error message in Moq

```
Message: Test method [...] threw exception: 
Moq.MockException: IVeracrossAPI.Authorization = Basic Og== invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.
```

Seems obvious. Unfortunately, in my code I already have this:

```
var VeracrossMock = new Mock<IVeracrossAPI>(MockBehavior.Strict);

var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password1234");
VeracrossMock.Setup(a => a.Authorization).Returns(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)));
```

So now I'm not sure how `IVeracrossAPI.Authorization` is missing. What's an approach to figure out what is *really* going on?

Comment: When using strict behavior it means that for a mock any member being called must have a corresponding setup or it will throw an exception. When you use loose behavior then when you call a member that was not setup then it will just return the default type of the member result.

Comment: @Nkosi I understand that, I'd like to use Strict behavior and also figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: The current setup will work for getting the value. You appear to try to **set** the value which has not been setup. Remember properties are basically two methods in one.

Comment: Check docs here https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties

Comment: @Nkosi Ah, I see, I need to re-read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `MockBehavior.Strict` it means that for a mock any member being invoked must have a corresponding `Setup` or it will throw an exception.

When you use `MockBehavior.Loose`, which is also the default, then when you call a member that was not setup then it will just return the default type of the member result.

The current setup shown will work for getting the value from the property.

From the exception it appears the test tries to set the value which has not been setup. Remember properties are basically two methods in one (get_Property and set_Property).

Suggest stubbing the property so that it keeps track of assigned values.

```
// start "tracking" sets/gets to this property
VeracrossMock.SetupProperty(_ => _.Authorization);

var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password1234");
var authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",  Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
//set value
VeracrossMock.Object.Authorization = authorization;
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart: Properties](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties)